# Android - Replace a text file from a server with an extended line

Tags: java, android

I have a text file on a server, now if the user presses a button, the text file should get a new line .
My idea was to create a text file on the device...to read the actual text file of the server...to append 'this new line' and upload it to the server, but this way isn't safe, are there other ways to do this ?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the server is a Web Server, you can simply send an Http request (Using HttpUrlConnection for example) from your application to a specific PHP file on the server, and put in this file (PHP file) the code to append a new line to the file or event to append a custom text content which you send it with the request.

Answer (score 0):

No need to read the existing text from the server unless you need them on the device, if you you need is to add a new line of text, you just need to send the text from the device to the server and and append the text to the text file on the server.